# Exporting SQL query results into CSV file

Tags: perl

How can i redirect Oracle SQL query results into a external CSV file on the drive at the same time printing them onto the screen in perl

here is what i'am planning to do

```
my $dbh =  DBI->connect('dbi:ODBC:Test2', 'XXX', 'XXXX') || die ("Connection Failed      \n");
$sql="select a,b from xxx";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();
my $dat;
```

while( $dat = $sth->fetchrow_hashref() ){
   print ("$dat->{a}",print ("$dat->{b}"   *** here i'am getting the results on the screen
    }

```
**My main challenge is to get the results into a csv file on my local disk -- Any   help    would be appreciated.....**
```

Comment: One possibility is to use the [Log::Dispatch](https://metacpan.org/module/Log::Dispatch) module, with directives that log output should be directed to both `File` and `Screen`

Comment: You could also open the output CSV file with `tail -f` or `less` and press `F` on your linux shell while running your program in another shell. If you want to know how to connect to the DB and query it, please ask specifically and provide code that you have already tried.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the CPAN module **Text::CSV**. This module will handle all the CSV specific handling (such as quoting).

```
use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new ( { binary => 1 } )  # should set binary attribute.
             or die "Cannot use CSV: ".Text::CSV->error_diag ();
open $fh, ">:encoding(utf8)", "my.csv";
```

.
.
.

```
while( $dat = $sth->fetchrow_hashref() ){ 
    print "$dat->{a} $dat->{b}\n";
    $csv->print ($fh, [ $dat->{a}, $dat->{b} ]);
}
```

.
.
.

```
close $fh or die "Failed to write CSV: $!";
```